# How to fix or solve the start up error in android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

just installed android studio and i keep getting the start up failed error.

already tried re-installing, Invalidate caches and restart, clean and rebuild project.

[image]

> startup failed: build file
>   'C:\Users\JR\AndroidStudioProjects\Guessit\app\build.gradle': 1:
>   unexpected token: < @ line 1, column 1.    < ? xml version = "1.0"
>   encoding = "UTF-8" ? >    ^
>
> 1 error

Open File

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this can be the issue as per your screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a hurry to fix this just like me, do this:
back up your codes,
go to `users/user/AndroidStudioProjects` then delete your proj,then
re-install.

Answer (score 0):

in u r project go to file than click on Re_import Gradle Project than re import u r dependencies